# chop unused decimals with javascript

Tags: javascript, decimal

I've got a currency input and need to return only significant digits. The input always has two decimal places, so:

```
4.00  ->  4
4.10  ->  4.1
4.01  ->  4.01
```

Here's how I'm currently doing it:

```
// chop off unnecessary decimals
if (val.charAt(val.length-1) == '0') { // xx.00
    val = val.substr(0, val.length-1);
}
if (val.charAt(val.length-1) == '0') { // xx.0
    val = val.substr(0, val.length-1);
}
if (val.charAt(val.length-1) == '.') { // xx.
    val = val.substr(0, val.length-1);
}
```

which works, and has a certain directness to it that I kind of like, but maybe there's a prettier way.

I suppose I could use a loop and run through it three times, but that actually seems like it'll be at least as bulky by the time I conditionalize the if statement. Other than that, any ideas? I imagine there's a regex way to do it, too....

Answer (score 15):

I believe [parseFloat()](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/tryit.asp?filename=tryjsref_parsefloat) does this.

```
parseFloat(4.00) // 4
parseFloat(4.10) // 4.1
parseFloat(4.01) // 4.01
```

Comment: A float may not have enough precision to accurately represent a given decimal value; you should never use them to represent currency.

Comment: That's true                  .

Comment: I think they'll be represented correctly as long as you don't do operations on them. And you can't do operations in decimal in JavaScript anyhow (without a decimal library that uses strings or an array of integers internally).

Answer (score 15):

Your code also chops off zeros in numbers like "1000". A better variant would be to only chop of zeros that are after a decimal point. The basic replacement with regular expressions would look like this:

```
str.replace(/(\.[0-9]*?)0+$/, "$1"); // remove trailing zeros
str.replace(/\.$/, "");              // remove trailing dot
```

Comment: Better to use 0+ instead of 0* so the regex doesn't match if there's no trailing zeros.

Comment: You're right, 0* with zero 0s matched doesn't do anything useful. But at least it also doesn't do any harm.

Comment: For the future researchers: previous comment is no longer relevant

Answer (score 4):

```
string to string: parseFloat(value).toFixed(2);
string to number: +(parseFloat(value).toFixed(2))
number to number: Math.round(value*100)/100;
number to string: (Math.round(value*100)/100).toFixed(2);
```

Answer (score 3):

I think this is what you want

```
    v = 33.404034
    v.toFixed(2) # v -> 33.40
    parseFloat(v.toFixed(2)) # 33.4
```

and you have

```
    v = 33.00704034
    v.toFixed(2) # v -> 33.01
    parseFloat(v.toFixed(2)) # 33.01

    v = 33.00304034
    v.toFixed(2) # v -> 33.00
    parseFloat(v.toFixed(2)) # 33
```

Answer (score 2):

So you're starting with a string and you want a string result, is that right?

```
val = "" + parseFloat(val);
```

That should work. The more terse

```
val = "" + +val;
```

or

```
val = +val + "";
```

would work as well, but that form is too hard to understand.

How do these work? They convert the string to a number then back to a string. You may not want to use these, but knowing how the JavaScript conversions work will help you debug whatever you do come up with.

Answer (score 1):

```
String(4) // "4"
String(4.1) // "4.1"
String(4.10) // "4.1"
String(4.01) // "4.01"
```

parseFloat works, but you've got to cast it back to a string.

Answer (score 0):

I am trying to find a solution like that right now. This is how I got here.

I used Number() function for my application, but looks like it's working the same as parseFloat()

http://jsfiddle.net/4WN5y/

I remove and commas before checking the number.

```
 var valueAsNumber = Number( val.replace(/\,/g,'') );
```