# Counting with Decimals Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have this code which is counting perfectly but the client wants it to count from 16.5 to 9.99. I'm sure it's possible to make the ending digit contain two decimal numbers. As an option in the bottom of the code, you will notice there's a decimal option. Maybe halfway through the count I can change it from 1 decimal to 2 decimal points? How can I do this? Thanks!

```
(function($) {
$.fn.countTo = function(options) {
    // merge the default plugin settings with the custom options
    options = $.extend({}, $.fn.countTo.defaults, options || {});

    // how many times to update the value, and how much to increment the value on each update
    var loops = Math.ceil(options.speed / options.refreshInterval),
        increment = (options.to - options.from) / loops;

    return $(this).each(function() {
        var _this = this,
            loopCount = 0,
            value = options.from,
            interval = setInterval(updateTimer, options.refreshInterval);

        function updateTimer() {
            value += increment;
            loopCount++;
            $(_this).html(value.toFixed(options.decimals));

            if (typeof(options.onUpdate) == 'function') {
                options.onUpdate.call(_this, value);
            }

            if (loopCount >= loops) {
                clearInterval(interval);
                value = options.to;

                if (typeof(options.onComplete) == 'function') {
                    options.onComplete.call(_this, value);
                }
            }
        }
    });
};

$.fn.countTo.defaults = {
    from: 0,  // the number the element should start at
    to: 100,  // the number the element should end at
    speed: 1000,  // how long it should take to count between the target numbers
    refreshInterval: 100,  // how often the element should be updated
    decimals: 1,  // the number of decimal places to show
    onUpdate: null,  // callback method for every time the element is updated,
    onComplete: null,  // callback method for when the element finishes updating
};
})(jQuery);


jQuery(function($) {
    $('#heroCounter').countTo({
        from: 16.5,
        to: 9.9,
        speed: 1500,
        refreshInterval: 50,
        onComplete: function(value) {
            console.debug(this);
        }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you want to change options dynamically? If yes http://jsfiddle.net/tarabyte/82qBL/3/

Add support for option get/set

```
$.fn.countTo = function(options) {
    if(typeof options === 'string') {
        var name = arguments[0],
            value = arguments[1];


        if(typeof value === 'undefined') { //getter
            var data = this.eq(0).data('countTo');
            return data && data[name];
        }
        return this.each(function(){ //setter
            var data = $(this).data('countTo');
            data && (data[name] = value);
        });
    }

    // merge the default plugin settings with the custom options
    options = $.extend({}, $.fn.countTo.defaults, options || {});
    ...
    $(this).data('countTo', options); //store current options in element's data
```

Change option onUpdate

```
$('#heroCounter').countTo({
    from: 16.5,
    to: 7.11,
    speed: 2900,
    decimals: 1,
    refreshInterval: 50,
    onUpdate: function(value){
        console.log($(this).countTo('from')); //get prop
        if(value < 10) {
            $(this).countTo('decimals', 2); //set prop    
        }
    },
    onComplete: function(value) {
        console.debug(this);
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

If I understand you should add `decimals` option:

```
    $('#heroCounter').countTo({
        from: 16.5,
        to: 9.9,
        speed: 1500,
        decimals: 2,
        refreshInterval: 50,
        onComplete: function(value) {
            console.debug(this);
        }
    });
```

or change `$(_this).html(value.toFixed(options.decimals));` to `$(_this).html(value.toFixed(2));`

[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/82qBL/)

**UPDATE:** @Guillermo Gutiérrez - `$(_this).html(value.toFixed(options.decimals, 2).toString().replace(/(\.[0-9]*?)0+$/, "$1"));`

[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/B2cEQ/1/)

Comment: The client wants it to count from 16.5 to 9.99 there for on the first number it should show 1 decimal place and then the last number should end with 2 decimal places. In this example you provided, it shows both numbers with 2 decimal places.

Comment: Check this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/B2cEQ/1/ Just modified line 19 from @user3388636 fiddle: `$(_this).html(value.toFixed(options.decimals, 2).toString().replace(/(\.[0-9]*?)0+$/, "$1"));` This SO post helped: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1015402/chop-unused-decimals-with-javascript